# Find whether sequence with general term $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{5^i+1}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Find whether the sequence whose general term is given by
$$a_n= \frac{1}{5+1}+\frac{1}{5^2+1}+.....+ \frac{1}{5^n+1}$$
 is convergent or divergent.

I compared this sequence with the sequence whose general term is

$$b_n=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5^2}+.....+ \frac{1}{5^n}$$

We know that  $b_n    $converges to $\frac{1}{4}$ and ${b_n} >{a_n}$, so $a_n$ will converge too.

Is my method correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's correct

Comment: For completeness, you might add that the terms are positive, so that the series is growing, and bounded above.

Comment: Your proof is fine, you can even have an upper bound for the resulting sum, as it will be between 0 and 1/4. It's even possible to refine it further by just subtracting, for example, $a_1 < b_1 -0.03$, so, as$ b_n < a_n$ for every single $n$, you can now claim your sum is less than 1/4-0.03. In short, your sum converges and does to something "quite small"

Comment: @YvesDaoust As the sequence converges, is it enough for the bounded above part, or would I have to prove that some other way?

Comment: @asdf oh yes, thanks!

Comment: @Sagar: I don't get your question, please rephrase.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ya ofcourse. I meant to ask, as you mentioned that it would be better to add that the series is bounded above, so do I have to prove that it is bounded above or is it pretty self evident that it is bounded above as it converges?

Comment: It converges to 0.21506...

Comment: @Sagar: it is the converse. It converges because it is bounded above. You can't prove that it converges by saying that it converges.